# Error C2679 when attempting to use std::wcout << wstring-var; vc++ 2008 express

Tags: unicode, visual-c++-2008-express

I'm getting a rather odd error message when attempting to wcout a wstring in vc++ 2008 express:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::wstring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

If I understand this correctly it's reporting that wcout does not accept a wstring? I ask someone to compile this code under linux and it runs fine. I also tried the same code on another computer with vc++ 2008 express and still fails. A known issue with std in vc++ 2008?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 std::wstring unicode_test = L"Unicode var";
 std::wcout << L"Unicode non-var" << std::endl;
 std::wcout << unicode_test << std::endl;    //<-- This line fails!
}
```

I'm using vc++ 2008 express sp1 with all the updates up to KB948127. I'm aware that console will need codepage changes but this isn't even compiling. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to `#include <string>`.  I'm not sure what the standard says, but I'm quite sure that `<iostream>` is not required to export all of `<string>`, if any.

[edit]At least [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) does not even list `string` as the types declared in `<iostream>`.  No, it's not the standard, I know...[/edit]

Comment: What fools you is that the line declaring a `wstring` works. Including <iostream> gets you enough of <string> to be able to declare one, but not `operator<<` - just helpful enough to hurt, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

For those with this problem, you may need to enable multi-byte printing in the console. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584090/1599699

And my comment:

> I was having trouble printing a wstring that I instantiated with a greater length than the data I was supplying due to sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(char) * 2, and then printing anything after that wasn't succeeding.