# How to initialize and print a std::wstring?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wstring

I had the code:

```
std::string st = "SomeText";
...
std::cout << st;
```

and that worked fine. But now my team wants to move to `wstring`.
So I tried:

```
std::wstring st = "SomeText";
...
std::cout << st;
```

but this gave me a compilation error:

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'const char [8]' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &'    D:...\TestModule1.cpp  28  1   TestModule1

After searching the web I read that I should define it as:

```
std::wstring st = L"SomeText"; // Notice the "L"
...
std::cout << st;
```

this compiled but prints `"0000000000012342"` instead of `"SomeText"`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Consider using ICU unicode library - [link](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/index.html). It supports unicode and has many usefull features. especially if you want to manipulate those strings.

Comment: @Weasel: Why in the world would you need a separate library to work with Unicode strings?

Comment: from my experience its much better to use a separate library   to manipulate wchar strings (search, replace etc) or other multi-byte strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I just needed to use wcout instead of cout (-:

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To display a wstring you also need a wide version of cout - wcout.

```
std::wstring st = L"SomeText";
...
std::wcout << st;
```

Answer (score 27):

Use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`.

Answer (score 14):

This answer apply to "C++/CLI" tag, and related Windows C++ console.

If you got multi-bytes characters in std::wstring, two more things need to be done to make it work:

1. Include headers

   `#include <io.h>`

   `#include <fcntl.h>`
2. Set stdout mode

   `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)`

Result:
[image: Multi-bytes console]

Comment: Thank you very much! It would have taken me a long time to figure this out... I was having trouble printing a wstring that I instantiated with a greater length than the data I was supplying due to `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(char) * 2`, and then printing anything after that wasn't succeeding. Your answer fixed the multi-byte printing problem so I could determine what was going on.

Answer (score 8):

try to use use  `std::wcout<<st` it will fix your problem.

```
std::wstring st = "SomeText";
...
std::wcout << st;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to print wide string:

```
std::wstring str1 = L"SomeText";
std::wstring strr2(L"OtherText!");

printf("Wide String1- %ls \n", str1.c_str());
wprintf(L"Wide String2- %s \n", str2.c_str());
```

- For **printf**:   **%s** is narrow char string and **%ls** is wide char string.
- For **wprintf**:  **%hs** is narrow char string and **%s** is wide char string.