# Wrong extended characters are represented

Tags: c++, string, char

I couldn't find any related answer to my question and I want to have a string like "╔══╗" but wrong characters are represented instead of them. I found the issue and that was because of signed characters and that values of each character is different with ascii table value of element. How can I do that with char in c++?

```
int main() {
    char a[] = "╔══╗";
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. `std::cout << "╔══════════════╗";` works as expected.

Comment: @churill I changed it thanks

Comment: @Mahdi Does `auto& a = u8"╔══╗";` also produce the wrong output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `std::wstring`(included in `<string>`) and `L"..."`:

```
#include <string>

int main(/**/)
{
    std::wstring wstr = L"╔══════════════╗";
}
```

NOTE: There is no good cross-platform way of printing such a string. See [How to print a wstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788057/how-to-initialize-and-print-a-stdwstring), [How to print a wstring on MacOs or Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512656/how-to-print-c-wstring-utf-8-characters-to-mac-os-or-unix-terminal), [C++ wide character locale doesn't work](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35353).

Comment: This skips the "_How can I do that with char in c++?_" part of the question.